# Deploy upgradable contracts using Remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, constructor, upgrading, contract-upgrading

How can I deploy a contract that has the `initialize` method from `Remix`? I have just seen [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/contracts-wizard/issues/155) that `Remix` now supports this feature but I haven't found any example I could follow.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do it.

You might be better off using Truffle and this tutorial: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/openzeppelin-upgrades-step-by-step-tutorial-for-truffle/3579

And then connecting to localhost: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html

---

Found this question because I've deployed upgradeable contract using Truffle and figuring out how to interact with it using Remix - I've just tested and it works, out of the box.